# Reading Exchangesymbols from CSV file - error

Tags: csv, python-import

When i want to run my python script i get this error:

File "", line 4
f.close
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Got the error at this section:

```
#read ticker symbols from a file to python list object named symbol
symbol = []
with open(r'C:/Users/nassir005/Documents/python/ExhangeSymbols.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        symbol.append(line.strip())
f.close
```

I have included the whole code below:

```
#settings for importing built-in datetime and date libraries
#and external pandas_datareader libraries

import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
import os
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\nassir005\Documents\python')

#read ticker symbols from a file to python list object named symbol
symbol = []
with open(r'C:/Users/nassir005/Documents/python/ExhangeSymbols.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        symbol.append(line.strip())
f.close


#datetime is a Python module
#datetime.date is a data type within the datetime module

#the start expression is for January 1, 2009
start = datetime.date(2009,1,1)

#the end expression is for October 7, 2019
end = datetime.date(2019,10,7)

#set path for csv file
path_out = 'C:/Users/nassir005/Documents/python/ouput'
file_out = 'yahoo_prices_volumes_for_ExchangeSymbols_from_01012009_07102019.csv'

#loop through tickers in symbol list with i values of 0 through
#index for last list item

#if no historical data returned on any pass, try to get the ticker data again
#if destination file is open in Excel, close Excel and continue data collection
#quit retries to get historical data for a symbol after tenth retry

i=0  #pointer for symbol
j=0  #count for loop within symbol
while i<len(symbol):
    try:
        df = web.DataReader(symbol[i], 'yahoo', start, end)
        df.insert(0,'Symbol',symbol[i])
        df = df.drop(['Adj Close'], axis=1)
        print ('from after dr', i,j, symbol[i])
        
        if i == 0:
            df.to_csv(path_out+file_out)
        else:
            df.to_csv(path_out+file_out,mode = 'a',header=False)
        j=0    
    except:
        print ('from except', i,j, symbol[i])
        if j <=9:
            print(i, symbol[i], j,'Eligible for retry')
            j = j+1
            continue
        if j == 10:
            j=0
            i=i+1
            continue
    i=i+1
```

Could somebody please help me with this issue?

Thank you.

Kamval

Answer (score 0):

Close is a function, not an attribute, so you have to type `f.close()`, instead of `f.close`.

Generally, in python, all functions call must have parentheses after the name, even if empty. Inside parentheses you can pass the arguments to be used inside the function.

If you don't have parentheses it means that you are accessing an attribute inside an object.

In this case `close` is a function, so the parentheses are needed.

Answer (score 0):

i have managed to make some adjustments to my code and it seems to work almost fine. However i still get the except block:

#settings for importing built-in datetime and date libraries
#and external pandas_datareader libraries

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
import os
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\nassir005\Documents\python')

#read ticker symbols from a file to python list object named symbol
def getdate():
    global symbol
    symbol = []
    with open(r'C:/Users/nassir005/Documents/python/ExhangeSymbols.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            symbol.append(line.strip())
    f.close()
    return symbol

symbol = getdate()
#datetime is a Python module
#datetime.date is a data type within the datetime module

#the start expression is for January 1, 2009
start = datetime.date(2009,1,1)

#the end expression is for October 7, 2019
end = datetime.date(2019,10,7)

#set path for csv file
path_out = r'C:/Users/nassir005/Documents/python/ouput'
file_out = r'yahoo_prices_volumes_for_ExchangeSymbols_from_01012009_07102019.csv'


#loop through tickers in symbol list with i values of 0 through
#index for last list item

#if no historical data returned on any pass, try to get the ticker data again
#if destination file is open in Excel, close Excel and continue data collection
#quit retries to get historical data for a symbol after tenth retry

i=0  #pointer for symbol
j=0  #count for loop within symbol
def getextra():
    global i
    global j
    while i<len(symbol):
        try:
            df = web.DataReader(symbol[i], 'yahoo', start, end)
            df.insert(0,'Symbol',symbol[i])
            df = df.drop(['Adj Close'], axis=1)
            print ('from after dr', i,j, symbol[i])
            if i == 0:
                df.to_csv(path_out+file_out)
            else:
                df.to_csv(path_out+file_out,mode = 'a',header=False)
            j=0    
        except:
            print ('from except', i,j, symbol[i])
            if j <=9:
                print(i, symbol[i], j,'Eligible for retry')
                j = j+1
                continue
            if j == 10:
                j=0
                i=i+1
                continue
        i=i+1
    return i, j

i, j = getextra()
```

This is been displayed. Dont know why this is happening...

[image]